# How to draw an image file stored in a subdirectory in Java

Tags: java, toolkit, drawimage

I'm trying to images in Java, and right now I'm using images that are in the local directory and it is working fine.  However, it would be nice if I could put the images in a folder and reference the path of the images to draw them, but I've been unable to do that so far.

Right now my code is essentially:

```
Image theImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(path);
g.drawImage(theImage,left,right,component);
```

And this works fine as long as iconPath is a local path.  But I can't figure out how to get it to work for non local paths or subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) shows many ways to load an image.

Don't forget you can always use a fully qualified path like "c://java/images/some.gif".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ImageIO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) utility class to load images from file paths.

Example:

```
/* at top of file */
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
/* in your code */
Image theImage = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
```